# Better way of Seeding a Pivot Table

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, pivot-table

I have the following tables **users** , **roles** and the pivot table **role_user** with the following table structure

users

- id
- username
- password

roles

- id
- role

role_user

- id
- role_id
- user_id

  ```
      <?php
           class PivotTableSeeder extends Seeder {
               public function run()
               {
                // Seeds the roles table
                  DB::table('roles')->delete();

                  DB::table('role_user')->insert(array(
                  array('user_id' => 1, 'role_id' => 1),
                  array('user_id' => 2, 'role_id' => 2),
                  array('user_id' => 3, 'role_id' => 1),
                  array('user_id' => 3, 'role_id' => 3),
                  array('user_id' => 3, 'role_id' => 5)
              ));
              }
          }
  ```

The pivot table is seeded using `DB select`

Is there a better way to seed the tables, including the pivot table?

I was thinking maybe when I seed my users table, it will also seed the role_user table instead of manually inserting the data into the pivot table.

Example:

roles

- id = 1
- role = encoder
- id = 2
- role = tech
- id = 3
- role = sales

users

- id = 1
- username = user
- password = pass
- id = 2
- username = user2
- password = pass2

role_user

- id = 1
- user_id = 1
- role_id = 1
- id = 2
- user_id = 1
- role_id = 2
- id = 3
- user_id = 2
- role_id = 3

---

**Edit**

I am seeding my users table by using this Eloquent.
Is there anyway that while seeding the User, the role_user will also get updated?

```
User::create(array(
    'id' => '1',
    'username' => 'user',
    'password' => 'pass'
));
User::create(array(
    'id' => '2',
    'username' => 'user2',
    'password' => 'pass2'
));
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may try this (Assuming that you have already seeded roles):

```
$user = User::create(['id' => '1', 'username' => 'user', 'password' => 'pass']);
$user->roles()->sync([1,2]); // array of role ids

$user = User::create(['id' => '2', 'username' => 'user2', 'password' => 'pass2']);
$user->roles()->sync([3,4]); // array of role ids
```

I've used `[]` instead of `array()`, if your `PHP` is prior to `ver-5.4` then you should use `array()`.

Comment: That's not creating the roles, and doesn't `attach()` limit you to one record? So you'd have to run multiple inserts to add multiple roles to a user?

Comment: Roles are already created according to his code in question, only attaching with created roles.

Comment: I was thinking he want to attach one role to each user but for multiple roles `sync` should be used, thanks @ollieread :-)

Comment: @WereWolf-TheAlpha was just wondering, I seeded the database using your answer and I noticed that the `created_at` and `updated_at` columns were not updated?

Comment: It has nothing to do with seeding.

Comment: What if the roles are  seeded too?

Answer (score 8):

For testing purposes I use pretty simple and fast method like below.

Imagine we have users and categories with pivot table (this comes from JeffreyWay's generators btw):

```
<?php

// Composer: "fzaninotto/faker": "v1.3.0"
use Faker\Factory as Faker;

class UsersTableSeeder extends Seeder {

    public function run()
    {
        $faker = Faker::create();

        foreach(range(1, 100) as $index)
        {
            User::create([
                'username'   => $username = $faker->userName,
                'email'      => $faker->email,
                'password'   => Hash::make($username),
                'account_id' => $index
            ]);
        }
    }

}

// all other seeders look the same, so I paste just the code that matters:
// Categories
    foreach(range(1, 30) as $index)
    {
        Category::create([
            'name' => $faker->word
        ]);
    }

// pivot table
    foreach(range(1, 50) as $index)
    {
        DB::table('category_user')->insert([
            'category_id' => rand(1,30),
            'user_id' => $faker->unique()->randomNumber(1, 100)
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: But can it generate including the relationship? I'm sorry if this may sound silly but I am not familiar with using Faker.

Comment: It can't generate it automatically, but as you can see in my example it requires 2 simple lines of code: random id from 1 to max, where max is hardcoded. Really, it takes like 5 mins to seed several tables this way.

Answer (score 3):

For n:m Relationships, where I need to attach random entries, I use this simple but efficient Seeder code, that only uses real ids:

```
    $faker = Faker\Factory::create();

    $limit = 100;

    for ($i = 0; $i < $limit; $i++) {
        $newrow = *Yourmodel*::create ([
            'email' => $faker->word . rand(0, 9999) . '@test.com' ,
          ...
        ]);

        $ids = $faker->randomElements( \App\YourOtherModel::select('id')->get()->toArray(), rand(1,*3*) );
        foreach($ids as $id) {
            $newrow->*your_relationship*()->attach( $id );
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how others feel about this, but when seeding the database, I like to use the actual models for the seeding, that way you can use all the handy functions that come with inserting related models.

If you're seeding the user and roles with predefined ids, then it's easy.

```
class UserSeeder extends Seeder
{

    public function run()
    {
        DB::table('users')->truncate();
        DB::table('roles')->truncate();
        DB::table('user_roles')->truncate();

        $users = [];

        $user = User::create(['id' => 1, 'blah' => 'honk']);
        $users[$user->id] = $user;
        $user = User::create(['id' => 2, 'blah' => 'honk']);
        $users[$user->id] = $user;
        // etc etc

        $roles = [];
        $role = Role::create(['id' => 1, 'blah' => 'honk']);
        $roles[$role->id] = $role;
        // etc etc

        $user[1]->roles()->sync(1);
        $user[2]->roles()->sync(2);
        $user[3]->roles()->sync(1, 3, 5);
    }

}
```

In a recent application I wrote, I created a seeder that created the ACL groups, then permissions, assigned the permissions to the specific groups, then randomly created somewhere between 10-30 (using `rand`) users and randomly assigned them to different groups.

Let me know if anything is unclear.

Comment: Excellent. Are the users being seeded too? As in, is this entirely random testing data or is this production ready data?

Comment: Yes the users are being seeded, this only for testing data.